# Loading images from non-accessible directory with PHP - concerns about content type and method

Tags: php

I need to call and load images from a non-web accessible directory and am doing this with PHP.

Essentially I use:

```
<img src="https://example.com/fetch_image.php?image=image_name.png" />
```

The script itself looks like:

```
$displayimage = file_get_contents('/home/whatever/public_html/db/uploads/'.$_GET['image']);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $displayimage;
```

Now, this seems to work fine. But what I am unsure about is:

- Is this the sensible way to do it?
- What header should you use if you are calling a wide variety of image formats? Using image/jpeg doesn't seem to stop the loading of PNG etc?
- Does the above approach create any security issues? I could in theory add a hashed and salted key to the URL parameters if needed (and then checked), but I didn't see the point.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the sensible way to do it?

Yes, but not like this. One rule of thumb: When security is a concern, always consider the way you treat user inputs.

For example: `https://example.com/fetch_image.php?image=../database.php` would access the parent folder and "download" the contents of the `database.php`.

As long as your script is not taking care of any access rights / logging whatsoever, simply put your images into an accessible folder of your liking, e.g. `assets`.

> What header should you use if you are calling a wide variety of image formats? Using image/jpeg doesn't seem to stop the loading of PNG etc?

For getting the proper [MIME-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type), you may want to take a look at [finfo_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).